# Optimal Graph path containing n nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, path

Is there an established algorithm for finding a path from point A to point B in a directed-weighted graph which visits exactly N nodes, but not necessarily any nodes in particular?

Answer (score 4):

This problem is known to be NP-hard via a reduction from [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path).  In particular, you can solve Hamiltonian path with a polynomial-time reduction to this problem as follows: for each possible pair of nodes (s, t) in a graph with n nodes, ask if there is a path from s to t that passes through exactly n nodes.  This makes only polynomial calls to your solver, so any polynomial-time solution to your problem would result in a polynomial-time solution to the Hamiltonian path problem.

So in short, you shouldn't expect a polynomial-time algorithm for this problem unless P = NP.

Comment: I like your approach, but the actual reduction doesn't seem quite right or complete.  A Hamiltonian path exists IFF the graph contains an edge, (u,v), such that there exists a path from v to u which visits n nodes.  (So, call the solver once for each edge in the graph to determine if there is a Hamiltonian path).

Comment: @Tom Sirgedas I think that would characterize a graph with a Hamiltonian cycle, not path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're trying to find the shortest/longest weight with N nodes. This probably isn't optimal, but from your original graph, you could generate a state graph with 'N*(#Nodes)' nodes representing consisting of the original node and number of steps taken and run it thorough some shortest path algorithm like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm.

i.e.,

```
A->B->C
 \___/
```

becomes

```
(A,0)->(B,1)->(C,2)
  \>(C,1)
```

Your target node would then be node (B,N) - B with N steps.  This approach would allow for loops in the original graph if it's not a DAG ( (X,0)->(Y,1)->(X,2) )

Comment: The problem I'm running into is that there are multiple paths connecting particular nodes, so it's not just A->B->C vs. A->D->C, its more along the lines of A-1->B-3->C vs A-2->B-1->C

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're saying, but let me clarify a bit - for each node T in the original graph, we generate N nodes `(T,0), (T,1), (T,2)...(T,n)`.  For each edge T->Y in the original graph, we create an edge between `(T,k)` and `(Y,k+1)`. for all K.  Thus, the path through the graph should always be ascending by one `(A,0)->(B,1)->(D,2)' etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I undersand it correctly, can you do a depth first search (up to N-1 layers away from the source)?

If you can visit your destination in that layer. you can get a path down there.